# pgadmin generate report with tables and columns

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

It's relatively easy to generate report with tables names. Right click on database -> reports -> object list report.

I get really nice report containing all tbales in the database but I would really love to also have there column names embeded.

Is it possible?

What would be the other way to export the full structure of the database (execially tables and columns) to the readable format?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
```

and then export the results.